# Call C++ function which returns a struct from C and use the result

Tags: c++, c

I have a code which in written mainly in C, but I have to call a C++ function from a .cpp file which returns a struct defined on this .cpp. I am totally begginer in C++ but I know that in order to make the call, I have to declared the C++ function with the words " extern "C" " before. However, I am not sure how can I work with the struct returned by this C++ function, I mean, I don't know how to declare it.

Here's some pseudocode:

.cpp file:

```
struct my_struct{
    ~my_struct() {
        if (name!= nullptr)
            free(name);
    }

public:
    int n = 0;
    char* name = nullptr;
};

extern "C" my_struct function_cpp(data_from_c);

my_struct function_cpp(data_from_c){
    my_struct output;
    //do things with data_from_c and store the results in output
    return output;
}
```

.c file:

```
my_struct function_cpp(data); // how can I declare this??

void main(){
    //some operations on a variable called data...
    results_from_cpp = function_cpp(data); // how I declare here results_from_cpp??
    //do things with results_from_cpp
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: extern C can take braces for a whole file if needed.  Then use a header and good

Comment: You can't use the structure in C code because it has C++-only features (the destructor and the `public` access specifier (which isn't needed for `struct`)).

Comment: Most C code can be compiled as C++. Is there any reason you can't compile all the code as C++? That will be a lot simpler than calling C++ from a C program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so if I don't use the destructor and the public specifier I can use the struct in both C++ and C?

Comment: It is easiest to define the struct in C and use it in C++

Answer (score 0):

Here you are actually declaring a class:

```cpp
struct my_struct{
    ~my_struct() {
        if (name!= nullptr)
            free(name);
    }

public:
    int n = 0;
    char* name = nullptr;
};
```

The difference between classes and structs in c++ is that classes are default private and structs are default public, but structs with functions are basically classes.

Remember that C has no idea of the coupling between data and methods. If you need to exchange structs between C and C++ the best way to do it is by declaring that struct in a `.h` file, this should be a C header file that can be included in the C part of your code.
If you **must** declare it in your C++ file make sure your struct has no functions or data class members (ex. use `char*` instead of `std::string`) since C won't know to call the destructors and contructors.

Also on a C++ class the code above would produce a class with a private destructor, that's no good. 
Also, `public` is redundant in C++ structs, members are assumed as public by default (in contrast with classes).

`my_struct function_cpp(data); // how can I declare this??`

That should be declared in a `.h` file shared between the C++ and C programs.

Then you compile the C++ part of the code into an object file with a c++ compiler.

And, finally, link it with the C code at compile time.

Comment: Really helpfull, thank you so much! I follow what you said and it works